# Ways of showing a webpage in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have a UIwebview which loads up a page ,first the links in the page were opening up on the same page, that made it look ugly, then I found a function which made the link open up in the phone's safari browser.That was nice but actually I want to show the links in a pop up view which can simply be closed. I have seen the google map popping up and showing the map. I want to do the same same thing with the links on the page they should open up as pop up and should not open up in safari and neither in the same UIWebview.
What could be the possible way to implement this.

Another inspiration is phonegap's ChildBrowser which opens the link as a popup.
I want to implement the same in native.
Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `UIWebview` to show the web content for the link. just `resize` it by using `frame` **property** as per your requirement because it's inherited by `UIView`.